# How to make a navbar responsive bootstrap

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i am trying to make a navbar in laravel with bootstrap, i am not that good in front-end so i am learning. The navbar in bigger screen shows good but in smaller one the buttons are more to the right side of the screen. This is the code that i have done:

Html:

```
<div>
<nav id="sidebar" class="active">

<div class="text-start">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/img/cash-flow.png') }}" class="image" alt="logo" class="app-logo">
    </div>

    <div class="horizontal-menu">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="/"><button class="dropDownButton"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Dashboard</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropDownButton">
                        <i class="fas fa-list"></i>
                         Veprime</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="/orders"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Porosite</a>
                        <a href="/outlay"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></i>&nbsp;Konfirmo shpenzim</a>
                        <a href="/cash-received"><i class="fas fa-receipt"></i>&nbsp;Konfirmo Arketim</a>
                        <a href="/my-actions"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-user-pen"></i>&nbsp;Veprimet e mia</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropDownButton">
                        <i class="fas fa-solid fa-check-to-slot"></i>&nbsp;Arka</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="/cash-register"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i>&nbsp;Arka</a>
                        <a href="/convert"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>&nbsp;Konvertim</a>
                        <a href="/currencies"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-hand-holding-dollar"></i>&nbsp;Monedhat</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropDownButton">
                        <i class="fas fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>&nbsp;Administrimi</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="/users"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp;Perdoruesit</a>
                        <a href="/roles"><i class="fas fa-random"></i>&nbsp;Rolet</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/actions"> <button class="dropDownButton"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-file-invoice"></i>&nbsp;Faturimi</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/outlay/employee"><button class="dropDownButton"><i class="fas fa-regular fa-share-from-square"></i>&nbsp;Shpenzimet e mia</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" id="nav2" class="nav-item nav-link dropdown-toggle text-secondary" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <button class="dropDownButton">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <span>{{ auth()->user()->name }}</span>
                        </button></a>

                    <div class="dropdown-profile">
                        <a href="/profile" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>&nbsp;Profili</a>
                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" class="dropdown-item">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt">
                            </i>&nbsp;Logout
                        </a>
                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
    @include('partials.menu-horizontal')
```

CSS

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
    integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Font Awesome-->
<link
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
/>

<!-- Google Fonts-->
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
/>
<!--MDB-->
<link
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.1.0/mdb.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
/>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.1.0/mdb.min.js"
></script>

<style>

    .dropDownButton {
        background-color: white;
        color: #6c757d;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        width:200px;
    }

    .horizontal-menu{
            width:850%;
            top:10px;
            margin-left: 210%;
    }

    .dropdown {
        width:90px;
        margin-top: -55px;
        margin-left: 6%;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        width: 200%;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-profile {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        width: 220%;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-profile a{
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    a{
       color:#6c757d;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #2196f3; color:white;}

    .dropdown-item:hover {background-color: #2196f3; color:white;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-profile {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropDownButton {background-color: #2196f3; color:white;}

    .image{
        width:100px;
        height:48px;
        margin-left: 150%;
    }
</style>
```

How it looks like in smaller screen:

[image]

How it looks in bigger screen:
[image]

As you can see the admin is off the screen i need the navbar to stay static to the changes. My css is for sure bad as i said im learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my code by using this example in `W3SCHOOLS`. [Code Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper way of using navbar of bootstrap.
Check out this method in which the use of css is minimal, and mosly used boostrap class and components

```css
.navbar-logo {
  width: 140px;
}
.dropdown-menu{
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.dropdown-item > i ,.nav-link > i{margin-right:8px;}
.nav-link{white-space:nowrap}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid navbar-logo" src="https://cashflow.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/CashflowLogo.png" />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Dashboard</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-list"></i>Veprime
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-plus"></i>Porosite</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></i>Konfirmo shpenzim</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-receipt"></i>Konfirmo Arketim</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-user-pen"></i>Veprimet e mia</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-solid fa-check-to-slot"></i>Arka
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i>Arka</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>Konvertim</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-hand-holding-dollar"></i>Monedhat</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>Administrimi
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Perdoruesit</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-random"></i>Rolet</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-file-invoice"></i>Faturimi</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-regular fa-share-from-square"></i>Shpenzimet e mia</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>Admin
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>Profili</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt">
                            </i>Logout</a></li>


            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This can be helpful to someone else but in my situation this example from `w3schools` made the work. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

Comment: So you didnt evn check w3scholl before asking question here? @laraCoder

Comment: i did but didnt found this particular result